# WPML echo translated String

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

In my WPML->String Translation, I imported a .po file with all the translations I needed. I know at least a few of them are right, and "Translation is Complete" is checked.

As an example, I have a string that has the following :

**Context** : Careers

**Name** : Martial Artists

**String** : Martial Artists

**French Translation** : Pratiquants d'Arts Martiaux

Then I tried using the GetText function __() to have the string added to the return value of a shortcode :

```html
return '<h5>' . __('Martial Artists', 'Careers') . '</h5>';
```

But on the page (mysite/fr/careers/), the English name Martial Artists still appears.

On the page, ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE equals "fr" so the page knows it's supposed to be in French.

Am I using the wrong function ? Are there arguments I don't understand, or steps I'm missing ? I've spent 2-3 hours on this and come up with nothing.

Thanks so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you have the translated files located?

Have you tried putting them in wp-content/languages/themes?

Use a prefix for the po/mo files, like ('Careers-fr_FR.po') and also set the content+prefix to 'Careers' in the advanced tab in the WPML config. Not sure about the capital though.

Comment: I think that may be where I lack some understandsing. The .po file is in some random folder in my plugins. I didn't get the impression the file was important once it was uploaded ? Especially that for now the file consists of about 10 items just for testing purposes.

What is the use of the po file once its content have been uploaded in WPML ?